# In Django ORM, "values" and "annotate" are not working to group by

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have a table like this:

[image]

Now I want to sum up the meals on each date. I have written the code below. But it doesn't work as I wanted.

Model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    date_of_meal = models.DateField()
    morning_meal = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    mid_day_meal = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    night_meal = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_of_meal)
```

Code:

```
meals_list = Meal.objects.values('date_of_meal').annotate(mm=Sum('morning_meal'), mdm=Sum('mid_day_meal'), nm=Sum('night_meal'))
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'mdm': 0, 'mm': 1, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 
23), 'nm':
 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'mm': 1, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 23), 'nm': 0}, {
'mdm': 1, 'mm': 0, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 22), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm':
 0, 'mm': 1, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 22), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'm
m': 1, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 21), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'mm': 1,
 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 21), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'mm': 1, 'date
_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 20), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'mm': 1, 'date_of_me
al': datetime.date(2017, 3, 20), 'nm': 1}, {'mdm': 1, 'mm': 0, 'date_of_meal': d
atetime.date(2017, 3, 19), 'nm': 0}, {'mdm': 0, 'mm': 0, 'date_of_meal': datetim
e.date(2017, 3, 19), 'nm': 1}]>
```

It repeats same date multiple times.

But I wanted liked this:

```
<QuerySet [{'mdm': 1, 'mm': 2, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 23), 'nm':
 1}, 
{'mdm': 1, 'mm': 1, 'date_of_meal': datetime.date(2017, 3, 22), 'nm': 2},

............
............
so on........
]>
```

How can I get my expected output ?

Comment: Please include the `Meal` model as well.

Comment: I've added the `Meal` model.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.distinct('date_of_meal')` to the end of your queryset?

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman: Could you also check and add the query you get after annotation: `print(meals_list.query)`? I just want to make sure that `group by` is included there.

Comment: @Dan, `distinct` gives the following error : `NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backen
d`

Comment: What backend are you using? is it sqlite?

Comment: @AKS , in query, it groups by `date_of_meal`, `updated` and `timestamp`. I think the problem is in `class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-timestamp']`. I have removed the ordering and it's working fine now.

@fixmycode, I'm using `mysql`.

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman That's great!. It is always better to look at the query if you are not getting the expected results.

Comment: @AKS, Thank you very much. Actually I'm new at Django. I didn't know about this feature to see the query.

Comment: See the notes on [`values()` and `order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) for an explanation of this behaviour.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

(The answer is hidden in the comments, so I've turned it into a proper answer. I spend a few hours having the same problem.)

The key problem is that Django automatically adds the fields you sort on to `values()`. So in your case, you *think* you're doing `.values('date_of_meal')`. But because of the `ordering = ['-updated', '-timestamp']` on your model, django turns it into `.values('date_of_meal', 'updated', 'timestamp') instead...

With such an unexpected `.values()` you of course don't get the group_by behaviour you expect.

The solution is to "reset" the default ordering by either adding an empty `.order_by()` or, in your case, `.order_by('date_of_meal')`.

See [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

Comment: Thanks, I have spent half an hour trying to fix this problem

Comment: toook me FOREVER to figure this out (aka find this post.) Thank you!

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `ordering` in model's `Meta` class if the ordering is not necessary in every query to that table.