# Django QuerySet .order_by() method

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this code down here and from my understanding `order_by`  over writes the default behavior of the ordering option in the model’s Meta. see the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

my question is what criteria does the  `order_by()`  in this case use to order the QuerySet if there are no fields provided? Does it make a difference having it there?

```
        order.discounts.filter(voucher_id=OuterRef("pk"))
        .order_by()
        .values("voucher_id")
        .annotate(Sum("amount"))
        .values("amount__sum")
    )
```

Comment: TLDR; it's essential when you group by elements, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077018/11544538) once helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `order_by()` with no parameters removes all ordering from the queryset and results are returned in an unspecified order by the database

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

> If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call order_by() with no parameters

> If a query doesn’t have an ordering specified, results are returned from the database in an unspecified order. A particular ordering is guaranteed only when ordering by a set of fields that uniquely identify each object in the results. For example, if a name field isn’t unique, ordering by it won’t guarantee objects with the same name always appear in the same order.